# "Error: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist" when run `terraform init`

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I added `module` for bucket creation in `modules.tf` file:

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"

  bucket = "first-porky-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  control_object_ownership = true
  object_ownership         = "ObjectWriter"

  versioning = {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Also, I added a config to keep terraform.tfstate in that bucket in `config.tf` file:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "first-porky-bucket"
    key = "state/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

When I run `terraform init` I get an error:

```
 Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: S3 bucket does not exist.
│ 
│ The referenced S3 bucket must have been previously created. If the S3 bucket
│ was created within the last minute, please wait for a minute or two and try
│ again.
│
│ Error: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
│       status code: 404, request id: B3MK2FAZHTV8E6AY, host id: 0RmL3oksELl7mLsyNAhSwRPIV+j4mlxmXa3OSF2VcAweIV8q8V3Btd+yg/Td9nJ0SF3D/BJ5jW4
```

Earlier I run `terraform destroy` to clean up and run again, just for learning purposes to see how it works. On my AWS account manually I removed terraform.tfstate, and then I removed bucket. Now, I am trying to do it again from scratch. My goal is to create bucket, and backend using Terraform to keep there terraform.tfstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `first-porky-bucket` bucket first, before you can use it in a provider. You can't do both at the same time. So either you have to have:

- two different TF scripts, one for bucket, and second for the rest, and run them separately, or
- create bucket manually using AWS console or CLI, and then run your TF code.

Comment: Sorry, if I am correct there are two different scripts. The modules.tf creates bucket, whereby config.tf creates backend, or am I wrong?

Comment: @scene No those are not "two different scripts" they are just two terraform files in the same folder, which get applied at the same time. To make it a "different script" it would need to be in a separate folder and applied with a separate `terraform apply` command.

Comment: It works when I set manually Bucket on AWS.